# Rigid body activates, before it interacts with another object

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

[image: screenshot]
I want the pitcher on character's hand get hit by a plate and fall and then I want other plates to destroy the rest of the character but everything falls apart even before plate hits anything.

Comment: If you want the simulation of an object to start on a specific frame, keyframe its **animated** property to be enabled during the animated part and disabled as the simulation is supposed to start.

Answer (score -1):

yes learn how here:
1-3 // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEo_9AopfoQ

2-3 // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QY7iJmqsJf8

3-3 // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0VJmmPPvwA

Enjoy!

Comment: please do not paste links without any notes about what they contain. Any links should supplement your answer not be your answer.

Comment: Oh, OK thank you I will know from now on! 
Sorry about that.